# MVC after passing an array to a controller I see System.Int32[]

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with passing an int array to controller:

```
   Model.MyIntArrayField = new int[]{ 1,2,3 };
   ...
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyIntArrayField)
```

then in the controller I have

```
public ViewResult MyActio(FormCollection formValues)
{
    formValues["MyIntArrayField "] //and I see the value is System.Int32[]
}
```

how to retrieve the array values `1,2,3` ?

Comment: is it not possible to cast it as an int array and get the values you would normally? I'm curious to know the answer as generally I use the html collection helper to send arrays to and from the controller

Comment: doesn't model is a read-only property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HiddenFor does not work with collections.  Once rendered, it will create something like this:

```
<input name="MyIntArrayField" id="MyIntArrayField" type="hidden" value="System.Int32[]"/>
```

The actual values are never included in the markup.

One way to accomplish this (and there are MANY ways mind you), is like this:
Use a DisplayFor for your array field (I happened to call my display template "HiddenIntArray")

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyIntArrayField, "HiddenIntArray")
```

Then, in the "HiddenIntArray" template, is this code:

```
@model int[]
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i])
}
```

This will generate markup once rendered like this:

```
<input id="MyIntArrayField_0_" name="MyIntArrayField[0]" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input id="MyIntArrayField_1_" name="MyIntArrayField[1]" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input id="MyIntArrayField_2_" name="MyIntArrayField[2]" type="hidden" value="3" />
```

Then, in your POST action, you can get those values back out (again, MANY different ways)...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
    var val1 = collection["MyIntArrayField[0]"]; // == 1

    // do something
}
```

That way, using the form collection is not very elegant... why not use your view model and let the MVC model binder do its magic?
Like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyModel();
    this.TryUpdateModel(model);

    var val1 = model.MyIntArrayField[0]; // == 1

    // do something
}
```

OR

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    var val1 = model.MyIntArrayField[0]; // == 1

    // do something
}
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

One of the way of doing this is Encode on client side (`@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.MyIntArrayField));`) and passing array via ajax.

```
Model.MyIntArrayField = new int[]{ 1,2,3 };
```

**In View**

```
<script>
        var arrayId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.MyIntArrayField));

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ArrayFieldId: arrayId }),
            success: function (result) {
                // ...
            }
        });
</script>
```

Result will be.

[image]